# Difference between Timer.setTimeout and Timer.after

Tags: javascript, timer, famo.us

I was testing `Timer` of `famo.us` here

http://famo.us/docs/0.2.0/utilities/Timer

I am confused about the `after()`. Look like it's an internal engine tick of `famo.us` but how does it translate to second? Because 5000 was about 9 seconds. It doesn't line up with `setTimeout` at all.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function of `after` and `setTimeout` are similiar, however `setTimeout` is time based (milliseconds) where `after` counts famo.us engine "ticks"

If you're wanting something to happen after a certain amount of time use `setTimeout()`

If you're wanting to do something that can be done after a few frames (say for example, we want to poll a phone's accelerometer value or something, but not constantly) use `after()`

An engine cycle can take more than a millisecond, several really, it depends on the complexity of your scene and the performance of the browser/device, so you shouldn't use `after()` as a measurement of time.

Hope that clears things.